# Exibir dados do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho um bando de dados com informações de varias bandas, porém eu gostaria de puxar elas para a minha página frontal.

nome do banco: `dados`

Tabela chamada : `Artists`

onde nela eu tenho as informações :

- `imagem_small` ( nesse caso uso url armazenadas das imagens das bandas )
- `Name`   - nome da banda
- `spotify_popularity` - popularidade da banda

A ideia seria mostrar a imagem acima e o nome do artista abaixo em uma coluna com 7 artistas e que somente as bandas com a popularidade abaixo de 20 aparecesse na coluna aleatória.

seria igual a esse site http://pipocaplayfm.com/site/

esse código é o que estou usando para puxar o conteudo.
localhost estou usando, por isso nao tem senha o banco de dados.

pórem quero saber se tem algo de errado ou tenho que colocar algo a mais ... ja que o código nao funciona.

ps. eu copiei exatamente como esta ai .

```html
 $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dados";
    //conexão ao banco de dados
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    //consulta a tabela Artistas onde spotify_popularity é menor que 20 no total de 7 registros
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE spotify_popularity < 20 limit 7";

    $result = $conn->query($consulta);

    $i=1;
    echo '<div id="container">';

    while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo "<div id='box-".$i."' class='box'>";
        echo "<img src=". $dados["imagem_small"]. ">";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<span>". $dados["Name"]. "</span>"; 
        echo "</div>";
        $i++;
    }

    echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS:**

- Centraliza a div `container` com largura de 100%.
- Dispõe as divs class `box` lado a lado com margem de 10px

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #container {
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
    }

    .box {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px 10px;
    }
</style>
```

**PHP**

**PHP: com MySQLi**

```
<?php

    $imagem_small="";
    $Name="";

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "USUARIO";
    $password = "SENHA";
    $dbname = "NOME_DB";
    //conexão ao banco de dados
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    //consulta a tabela Artistas onde spotify_popularity é menor que 20 no total de 7 registros
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE spotify_popularity < 20 limit 7";

    $result = $conn->query($consulta);

    $i=1;
    echo '<div id="container">';

    while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo "<div id='box-".$i."' class='box'>";
        echo "<img src=". $dados["imagem_small"]. ">";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<span>". $dados["Name"]. "</span>"; 
        echo "</div>";
        $i++;
    }

    echo '</div>';
?>
```

> O nome da tabela **não é** `Artists` conforme dito na pergunta **e sim** `artists` conforme consta em https://snag.gy/6eBbAK.jpg

Comment: copiei ele e colei em uma pagina em php ...nada funciona.
tenho que fazer algo a mais ?

Comment: @jhonatansantos, se o exemplo que eu postei, cujo código é exatamente o da resposta está funcionando e para você não está, algo fora do nosso alcance para poder lhe dizer. Aproveita e leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484

Comment: eu apenas copio o código e colo - depois coloco as informaçoes do banco ...no caso senha e etc ???

Comment: @jhonatansantos o nome da sua tabela no banco é `artists` com a minusculo

Comment: eu adicionei na pergunta como ficou o seu código, mas ele apenas mostra o código e nao o conteúdo.

a minha dúvida é ...se tenho que fazer algo a mais, criar uma pagina para realizar algo. pois eu fiz assim :  criei uma pagina e colei o codigo.

Comment: Colocou o script  entre as tags de php? o nome do arquivo tem extensão .php ?

Comment: como aparece a minha pagina https://snag.gy/atOhdq.jpg  
como está o código da minha página e extensão dela https://snag.gy/TQDORw.jpg

Comment: @jhonatansantos estou trabalhando em um servidor online, localmente não é minha praia!

Comment: Vou testar amanhã online e te passo o feedback .

Comment: Testei online olha o link  http://pipocaplayfm.com/teste/bandas.php
nao funciona corretamente

Comment: podes fazer isso no codigo que vc sugeriu acima so pra mim entender ? sou leigo nisso cara.

Answer (score 0):

O certo é você disponibilizar um código para nos ajudar a lhe ajudar.
Mas segue um exemplo `basico` de como fazer.

```
<?php
    try {
       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname= dados', 
       'root', '');
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Artists");
    $sql->execute();

    while($ln = $sql->fetchObject()){
       echo '<h1>'.$ln->Name.'</h1>';
       echo '<img src="'.$ln->imagem_small.'">';

    }
```

Com isso, você já ira exibir o nome e a imagem da banda, e pode alterar o codigo para lhe atender melhor.

Comment: eu coloquei nenhum código pq eu não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.  com esse seu código o que mais preciso para conectar ao meu banco ?

Comment: @jhonatansantos Adicionei a conexão ao banco

Comment: apareceu o erro 
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ' dados'

Comment: Voce tem um banco de dados criado chamado `dados`?

Comment: sim tenho - https://snag.gy/6eBbAK.jpg